# How to integrate navigationBar with scrollable-tab-view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying this code  to create a  screen with navigationBar and a scrollable tab  something like this : 
[image]

Here  is my code :

```
import NavigationBar from 'react-native-navigation-bar';
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet , Text} from 'react-native';
import ScrollableTabView, { ScrollableTabBar, } from 'react-native-   scrollable-tab-view';
export default class HomePage extends   PureComponent{
 render() {
return (
 <NavigationBar
 title={'this is a test'}
 height={44}
 titleColor={'#fff'}
 backgroundColor={'#149be0'}
 leftButtonTitle={'back'}
 leftButtonTitleColor={'#fff'}
 rightButtonTitle={'forward'}
 rightButtonTitleColor={'#fff'}
  />
  <ScrollableTabView
 style={{marginTop: 20, }}
 initialPage={2}
 renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
 >
 <Text tabLabel='Tab #1'>My</Text>
 <Text tabLabel='Tab #2'>favorite</Text>
<Text tabLabel='Tab #3'>project</Text>
</ScrollableTabView>
)};
};
```

I get this error : `Adjacent   JSX elements must be wrapped  in an enclosing tag`

Hw can i fix it please .

Comment: "Adjacent   JSX elements must be wrapped  in an enclosing tag", maybe enclose your return with a div ? You can't return multiple JSX element in render (you do it with one navigationBar and one ScrallableTabView).

Comment: As this is react-native, you need to wrap your NavigationBar and ScrollableTabView in a View component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as error says, you need to wrap your code. You must have single returning element in `render()`

in react native:

```
return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    //place your content here
    </View>
);
```

in react:

```
return (
    <div>
    //place your content here
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two tags at the same level in your `return`.  If you wrap those tags in another tag that should fix the problem.

For example:

```
export default class HomePage extends   PureComponent{
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <NavigationBar
         title={'this is a test'}
         height={44}
         titleColor={'#fff'}
         backgroundColor={'#149be0'}
         leftButtonTitle={'back'}
         leftButtonTitleColor={'#fff'}
         rightButtonTitle={'forward'}
         rightButtonTitleColor={'#fff'}
       />
      <ScrollableTabView
        style={{marginTop: 20, }}
        initialPage={2}
         renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
      >
        <Text tabLabel='Tab #1'>My</Text>
        <Text tabLabel='Tab #2'>favorite</Text>
        <Text tabLabel='Tab #3'>project</Text>
      </ScrollableTabView>
    </div>
  )};
};
```